# Center CSS text rotating animation

Tags: css

I have a problem centering a text rotating animation. The first word appears correctly at the center of the page (centered both horizontally and vertically) but the second and third one appear at the top of the screen (only centered horizontally). I want them to appear at the center of the page one after the other. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code used:

```css
.slidingHorizontal{
 font-family: Helvetica ;
 font-size: 82px;
 text-shadow: grey 0px 0px 4px ;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline;
 text-indent: 8px;
    color: black;
}
.slidingHorizontal span{
 animation: leftToRight 7.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: leftToRight 7.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -webkit-animation: leftToRight 7.5s linear infinite 0s;
 opacity: 0;
 position: static;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(2){
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(3){
 animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
}


@-moz-keyframes leftToRight{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes leftToRight{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes leftToRight{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="slidingHorizontal">
      <span>FIRST</span>
      <span>SECOND</span>
      <span>THIRD</span>
</div>
```

Comment: "First" appears in the upper-left corner for me.

Comment: I see the same as @j08691. Changing `position: static;` in `.slidingHorizontal span` centers the text. (tested with latest Chrome on Mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first is showing on left corner for me as well.

have a look here, those are both centralized in the middle of the page

see the demo: jsfiddle.net/y5L5xb6a/